# How to dynamically load a function to test unit with exec()?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to load the function into the unit test dynamically, passing code as `str` and use `exec()` to run them in test.

My current code look like this:

```
import unittest

class ParametrizedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', param=None):
        super(ParametrizedTestCase, self).__init__(methodName)
        exec (param)
        self.param = param

    @staticmethod
    def parametrize(testcase_klass, param=None):
        testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
        testname = testloader.getTestCaseNames(testcase_klass)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for name in testname:
            suite.addTest(testcase_klass(name, param=param))
        return suite

class TestZero(ParametrizedTestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        print('param:', self.param)
        self.assertEqual(add(1,1), 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code = "def add(a, b): return a + b"
    suite = ParametrizedTestCase.parametrize(TestZero, param=code)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

and this is current out put:

```
❯ python test/test0.py
test_add (__main__.TestZero) ... param: def add(a, b): return a + b
ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_add (__main__.TestZero)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test0.py", line 21, in test_add
    self.assertEqual(add(1,1), 2)
NameError: name 'add' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Is it possible to do that and if so, how?

Comment: Ignoring why you want to do this in the first place, your error message doesn't match your actual code. `test_add` looks right, but your error message suggests a different definition.

Comment: @chepner thx for noticing this I might copy the wrong section of the terminal. will update soon.

Comment: @chepner update the error msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` with no additional parameters is defining `add` in the local scope of `ParameterizedTestCase.__init__`; once that function complete, `add` goes out of scope.

One solution is to put `add` in the global scope, so that it's accessible.

```
exec(param, globals())
```

However, in general you aren't going to know what name (or names) the execution of `param` will make available for future tests.